# Haskell loading modules problem in emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, module

I have 2 Haskell modules in emacs: Mod1.hs and Mod2.hs

Mod1.hs:

```
module Mod1 where
...
```

In the second module i try to import first module:

```
import Mod1
```

But get error:

```
 Could not find module `Mod1':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

In emacs i use standard Haskell-mode. Mod1.hs and Mod2.hs files in the same directory.

How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the search-path of the interpreter running in Emacs to include the directory with your files. In the GHCi interpreter do:

```
Prelude> :cd /home/you/projects/yourproject
```

Replacing `/home/you/projects/yourproject` with the path to your `.hs` files of course. (Do `:!pwd` in the interpreter to print the current path.) You should then be able to do:

```
Prelude> :l Mod2
```

(Or `C-c C-l` in the `Mod2.hs` buffer.) See [the GHC user guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

This may help, if you put it in your .emacs:

> ```
> (setq inferior-haskell-find-project-root nil)
> ```

It tells ghci not to move from the current directory.